# Installing Oversip on RHEL6 facing issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i am trying to install oversip 1.3.3 on RHEL 6 . but facing these issues. Can anyone help???  I have installed ruby 1.9.3.

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing oversip:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb        
[ext/stud/extconf.rb] executing system command: tar -zxf stud.tar.gz
[ext/stud/extconf.rb] RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] returns "linux-gnu"
[ext/stud/extconf.rb] executing system command: make
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

```
Provided configuration options:
         --with-opt-dir
         --without-opt-dir
         --with-opt-include
         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
         --with-opt-lib
         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
         --with-make-prog
         --without-make-prog
         --srcdir=.
         --curdir
         --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
 extconf.rb:14:in `sys': [ext/stud/extconf.rb] system command `make' failed (Runt
         from extconf.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
         from extconf.rb:27:in `chdir'
         from extconf.rb:27:in `block in <main>'
         from extconf.rb:24:in `chdir'
         from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/over
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/oversip-1.3.8/ext/stu

Here are few logs from :
    **/root/gems/gems/oversip-1.3.8/thirdparty/stud/mkmf.log**

```
"tar -zxf stud.tar.gz"
make
cc -O2 -g -std=c99 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -W -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/local/include   -c -o stud.o stud.c
stud.c:60:16: error: ev.h: No such file or directory
stud.c:87: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âlistenerâ
stud.c:130: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âev_ioâ
stud.c: In function âinfo_callbackâ:
stud.c:254: error: âproxystateâ has no member named âhandshakedâ
stud.c:255: error: âproxystateâ has no member named ârenegotiationâ
stud.c: At top level:
stud.c:731: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âev_ioâ
stud.c: In function âsafe_enable_ioâ:
stud.c:732: error: âproxystateâ has no member named âwant_shutdownâ
stud.c:733: warning: implicit declaration of function âev_io_startâ
stud.c:733: error: âwâ undeclared (first use in this function)
stud.c:733: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
stud.c:733: error: for each function it appears in.)
stud.c: In function âshutdown_proxyâ:
stud.c:739: error: âproxystateâ has no member named âwant_shutdownâ
stud.c:740: warning: implicit declaration of function âev_io_stopâ
stud.c:740: error: âproxystateâ has no member named âev_w_sslâ
stud.c:741: error: âproxystateâ has no member named âev_r_sslâ
stud.c:742: error: âproxystateâ has no member named âev_w_handshakeâ
```

Comment: Check the `mkmf.log` file inside the gem install directory, you should find a better description of the error. Also check if you have `make` installed.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I have checked make. And its installed. Then i checked the /stud/mkmf.log file and i got the above logs.

Comment: is it something related to path?? as i have installed libev-dlevel .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are missing the header file `ev.h` that comes from [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html). You have to install the package libev-devel.

**Update** On RedHat system the file `ev.h` is in the "wrong" place, i.e. `/usr/include/libev/ev.h`, therefore you have to create a symlink to build the gem:

```
ln -s /usr/include/libev/ev.h /usr/include/ev.h
```

This is a bug that will be fixed once the version 1.4 of OverSip will be released, see here: https://github.com/versatica/OverSIP/issues/23.

Comment: Awesome Sir!!! i just found the same bug. 
i did 
cp /usr/include/libev/ev.h /usr/include/ev.h

And it worked for me.
Thanks !! Thank you so much!!! :) :) :)

Comment: OverSip is installed... but to start oversip they have given a script:
https://github.com/versatica/OverSIP/issues/8

When i execute this script , it gives:
Starting oversip: /bin/bash: oversip: command not found
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: You have to add the path where the command `opensip` is installed to the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: yes added path :
Now i am able to run oversip like this:
oversip --pid /var/run/oversip/oversip.pid -u oversip

But when i put the same command inside a script & run then it gives me same error.

Comment: It's quite hard to tell, you should ask a question for this, maybe on Superuser.